# Is it possible to declare a user input string to be a variable in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA for Excel, is it possible to declare user input or cell value as a variable?

I am creating a spreadsheet where there is a long list (~150) of variable names and a user will enter values in the column adjacent to the name. I am looking for a way--if there is one--for the code to read in and declare each of those variables from the Range and then assign the respective user-input value without having to declare each variable name in the code manually.

Is this "possible"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy shortcut is to use the `CreateNames` method on the `Range` object. Although this doesn't create a VBA variable, it does create a new name on the worksheet which can be accessed through `Evaluate` or square brackets.

Example:

If the selection contains

```
  one    1  
  two    2  
  three  3
```

the following VBA code

```
  Selection.CreateNames Left:=True
  MsgBox [one]
```

will display 1. You can also use `Evaluate("one")` instead of `[one]` if you have `one` in a string variable.

Comment: Thanks, this nearly accomplishes my goal. I see it does assign the name in the spreadsheet under Name Manager. But I must be missing something (probably obvious)... I get a run-time error 13 "type mismatch" on the MsgBox output when attempting either syntax. I tried with and without the Explicit option... same error. What am I missing?

Comment: That could mean anything but probably means that the name is not defined. This is probably an interaction with something else in your worksheet, or maybe the active worksheet is not what you think it is.

Comment: I found the problem: I was applying it to a range that had 3 columns (name column, value column, units column) and hence the value assigned to the name was an array of the value and units.

What I have (and does not work), it thus:

A named ranged "Foo" like this:

one 1 ft
two 2 ft^2
three 3 ft^3

...and some code like this:

Sub Testing()
    
    Dim arr As Variant
    Set arr = Range("Foo")
    arr.CreateNames Left:=True
    MsgBox [one]
    
End Sub

Comment: My apologies for the messy reply--I am inexperienced in the formatting technique here.

Comment: Just as confirmation, your method does work for my original question with only minor spreadsheet adjustments and can be used in conjunction with other named arrays and such. Something I found to watch out for is--of course--to avoid names that already exist in VBA; these cause inconsistent handling with code compiling or running.